# Open graph maximum image aspect ratio is 3:1, what about minimum?

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, aspect-ratio, minimum

According to the open graph documentation the maximum aspect ratio for an image is 3:1. An aspect ratio, the way I understand it, is width to height. Hence given the 3:1 requirement the width of an image can be up to 3x the height.

This however, does not seem to set any limit on the height of an image? Is there a minimum aspect requirement as well? Otherwise it would seem you could have an image for example which is 50px wide, but 500px tall?

Thanks